# For loop to keep files in order

Tags: php

Linux box.

I need help trying to figure how to get my for loop to keep files in numerical order in the directory they are written to.

I have item1.php, item2.php etc...
but when it gets to item10.php it will be after item1.php, the only way I found to keep them in order is to put a zero in front of the 1st 9 files. But that's not been so easy in the code.

I tried making

```
for ($i = 01; $i < 45; ++$i) {
```

but the "0" is ignored.

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 45; ++$i) {
    if (!file_exists($dirPath . '/item'. $i . '.php')) {
        // fopen, frwite, fclose...
        $myfile = fopen($dirPath . '/item'. $i . '.php', "w") or die("Unable to open item$i file!");
        $txt = "something to write";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        fclose($myfile);
        break;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Bob

Comment: `but when it gets to item10.php it will be after item1.php` gets what and where it will be `after`? The loop you showed does not care about filesystem order - it follows from 1 to 44. So, what to you mean by `order`, where do you want to use it?

Comment: I trying to get , item01.php, item02.php, item09.php, item10.php in order in the directory, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 etc.. I don't want them mixed. I have a routine that grabs the names and puts them in a inframe, and if they are mixed they are not in the order submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why the order in a directory would matter, but if you really need it, you could use something like:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 45; ++$i) {
  $filename = $dirPath . '/item'. sprintf("%02s", $i) . '.php';
                                             ^ length of number you need, 2 in this case
  if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    $myfile = fopen($filename, "w") or die("Unable to open item$i file!");
    // etc.
```

See the manual on [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

By the way, I would not recommend writing to a php file, you might be introducing a security risk that way.

Comment: The php files are dynamically built web pages.

Comment: @bpross Yes, that's why I thought I'd mention it :-)

Comment: <iframe src ="item1.php" width="780" height="1000" frameborder="0"> </iframe>

Comment: Thanks. I have all the slashes stripped and only allows text and numbers in the few fields there are. Most are pull down and photo upload for rental inspections. It's not open to the general public. These are my own private pages for work. I have it set with SSL and also requires two logins to get to them.

Comment: Working great. Thanks so much!. Makes it a lot easier than hard coding those names. That will save 300+ lines of needless code.

Comment: @bpross If it's for yourself there is obviously no problem. However, can't you use a database instead of having to write to php files? I make a lot of dynamically built pages, but I have never had the need to write to a php file. Anyway, just a suggestion :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a string pad which is pretty straight forward. It will add zeros in front but only as a filler up to 2 digits so it will do 01-09 but not after that.

```
for($i = 1; $i < 45; ++$i) {
        // The second digit (2) is how many characters it will pad in front so
        // if you go past 2 digits, put it to 3 and it will be 001,002,003, etc...
        // then in double digits it switches to 010,011, etc...
        $i_mod  =   str_pad($i,2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
        if(!file_exists($dirPath . '/item'. $i_mod . '.php')) {
                // fopen, frwite, fclose...
                $myfile =   fopen($dirPath . '/item'. $i_mod . '.php', "w") or die("Unable to open item$i_mod file!");
                $txt    =   "something to write";
                fwrite($myfile, $txt);
                fclose($myfile);
                break;
            }
    }
```